# Outlook Web Add-in Contextual menu for Appointment

Tags: outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am building outlook web add-in basically replacing our existing VSTO outlook Add-in.  I was looking for a way to build context menu for appointment made via outlook web add-in but I couldnt find any samples or documentation for this.

[image]

Kindly help how to achieve the context menu on appointments or bring the `task pane add-in` in calendar view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently context menus is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins

Answer (score 1):

Context menus are not exposed to the Web Addins. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/add-in-commands-for-outlook for all available extension points.

Comment: sorry. May be I am missing some thing. I cant find where the docs say it is not available for Web Add-ins. I can see the following text `contextual add-ins can present different commands depending on whether the currently selected item is a message or appointment` . Kindly advise

Comment: Contextual add-ins are Outlook add-ins that activate based on text in a message or appointment. You can learn more about them at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins

Comment: Dear Outlook team, Your actual answer is stating that 'context menu is not part of the product`. Then what is the above link refers to ? Is it for VSTO Addin ?

Comment: Contextual add-ins and contextual menu are two different things. Contextual add-ins are a type of web add-in where as context menu is a feature of VSTO add-ins